# Use Column1 as column headers, use Column2 as rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-excel-365

I have a table in Excel that I've used in a PowerQuery query:

[image]

[image]

I want to pivot the table so that:

- Column1 is used as column headers
- Column2 is used as rows

Like this:

```
2                                  1
---------------------------------  --------------
Number of features returned: 100   SQL: SELECT...
Number of features returned: 100   SQL: SELECT...
Number of features returned: 100   SQL: SELECT...
Number of features returned: 100   SQL: SELECT...
Number of features returned: 100   SQL: SELECT...
Number of features returned: 138   SQL: SELECT...
```

How can I do that in Excel?

---

Related:

[Copy Diagnostic Monitor logs as Excel table, not as vertical tags](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/copy-diagnostic-monitor-logs-as-excel-table-not-as/idi-p/1278106)

Comment: if the row order was always the same then `WRAPROWS(B2:B14,2)` would work. If you want to do this in power query, use the pivot command, then click on advance and select do not aggregate

Answer (score 2):

You have the possibility of using formulas to achieve it. If you have Excel365:

- First, get the unique items from Column1, then transpose them:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A6))
```

[image]

- Second, filter the elements based on the headers:

```
=FILTER($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6=D2)
```

Drag the formula to fill the other column(s).

[image]